# Can't message Skype bot in preview mode

Tags: ms-office, bots, skype, skype-bots

I've added my Skype bot (in preview mode) to my Skype account. The Skype bot seems to be properly configured, as he respons to the `OnContactAddedAsync` event properly by replying a pre-defined message.

However, I cannot further test the `OnPersonalChatMessageReceivedAsync` handler, as I'm not able to message my bot, i.e., Skype shows me the following:

[image: Screenshot of the conversation with my bot]

Is it because I'm not added to the bot's contact list? If so, how to add somebody to the bot's contact list using the Skype Bot SDK? I have not found any way to do so in the `OnContactAddedAsync` handler.

Is it because of some other reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to (forcefully) update your Skype client to the lastet version in order to make it work.

- Skype v7.21.0.100 does not work.
- Skype v7.21.85.100 does work.
- Skype v7.22.85.107 does work.

When you add the bot to your contact list in the latter version, it automatically accepts the request and you are able to message the bot.